# variable visibility in thread synchronization

Tags: c++, multithreading

```
struct Info {
    int a;
    int b;
};
class A {
public:
    A() {
        _info = new Info;
        _info->a = 1;
        _info->b = 1;
    }
    void update()
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l(_m);
        _info->a = 2;
        _info->b = 3;
    }
    Info* get_info() {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l(_m);
        return _info;
    }
private:
    mutable std::mutex _m;
    Info* _info;
};

A a;

// in thread 1
a.update();

// in thread 2
Info* i = a.get_info();
std::cout<<i->a<<" "<<i->b<<std::endl;
```

Does it possible to print `1 3` or `2 1` ?

Comment: The code has a data race, and thus undefined behaviour. (Consider the case where thread 2 obtains the lock first.)

Comment: I know this code is problematic, but I can not find cpp's document which says this is an UB, could you give me an reference?

Comment: 1.10, the subclause on the memory model. I'm not sure what you need with the standard reference, though. The code has obviously got a race condition, and race conditions obviously have UB.

Comment: Well, unlike out of bounder access will make process crash, this code is harmless relatively. I can accept i's a b are both out-dated data or newest. So I ask this question

Comment: Out-of-bounds access will not make the program crash. There's no such guarantee. The behaviour of that, too, is undefined.

Comment: Theoretically, you are right. But that depends practically. Out-of-bounds access crash chance > 0, however this code, crash chance == 0. The UB "can happen anything" is an summary

Answer (score -1):

This is unspecified/undefined behavior

The objects being accessed are not protected by a mutex. The mutex is being held only long enough to read the pointer. The mutex is not held while accessing the contents of the pointer, as such the mutex offers no synchronization with `update()`.

Comment: The behaviour is undefined, not unspecified.